# Using window object

Tags: javascript

I've seen lots of people using `window.` when calling some variable. But aren't all the variables of a same window actually in `window`?
Example:

```
window.onorientationchange = function() {
  var orientation = window.orientation; // <-- WHY?
  switch(orientation) {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

But the same people use `alert()`, `document`, etc. So why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At certain times you want to expose only certain functions/variables to be *explicit* properties of the `window`.

```
(function() {
   var jQuery = function(selector) { alert( selector ) }
})();

jQuery // not defined
```

If we alter it to be:

```
(function() {
   var jQuery = function(selector) { alert( selector ) }
   window.jQuery = jQuery;
})();
```

then we "expose" it from a private namespace explicitly.

And yes, you do not have to explicitly declare `window.` to invoke methods such as `alert`, but everyone has their own style of coding and everyone has their own degree of how explicit their statements should be.

Some people explicitly prefix `window.` to global methods such as `alert` in order to avoid any confusion. Let's say you defined a function in a private namespace that was named `alert`, for example...

```
(function() {
   function alert() {}
   alert('lol'); // does nothing
   window.alert('lol') // does something
})();
```

We cannot use `alert` inside of that private namespace to do our alerting, since we defined a function with exactly the same name. We have to explicitly reference the `window.alert` method to get around that.

But for general purposes, I would say it's perfectly fine to not prefix things with `window.` unless you are exposing things in a private namespace to the global namespace. So please use `document` and `alert` and such as is, in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In many javascript tutorials alert(), document() and so on are used without fully qualified window object and I think they just repeat that code.